# How to change dekstop icon image on Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, icons

I created a desktop icon for a shell script

- Mint 17.1
- with Cinnamon
- nemo

The default icon was a red missile (?!)

**How can I change it to any other image?**

I found ways to style the caption, resize the image, etc. etc., but not the image itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just right click on the icon, choose properties and then click on the icon's image and browse to select the icon you want to use. I'm using the "Home" icon to illustrate:

[image: right click and choose properties]

[image: click on the icon]

[image: browse to the icon you want]

Comment: how evil of them not to write the words "change icon" ...